# How to avoid lag because of large bitmap images?

Tags: android, garbage-collection, serversocket, bitmapfactory

I am continuously receiving images from java server through `Socket` and displaying it in `ImageView`. 
But the Gargabe collector cause to skip more than 10 frames. Is there any way to avoid this condition.

```
public class ScreenCastActivity extends Activity {
PrintWriter printwriter;
static ImageView iv;
static Drawable ob;
Bitmap bitmap;
public static Socket client;
public static int port_add;
public static String port_addr;
public static String ip_add;
public static SendEvent task;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen_cast);
    ip_add=getIntent().getStringExtra("Ip");
    port_addr=getIntent().getStringExtra("Port");
    Log.i("IP and Port in SC",ip_add+","+port_addr);
    Serializer ma=new Serializer(4,"ScreenShot");
         String json=ObjectSerializer(ma);
            task=new SendEvent(json);
        task.execute();
}

class SendEvent extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap>{
    String json;

    public SendEvent(String json) {
        this.json=json;
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... arg0){
            try{
                port_add=Integer.parseInt(port_addr);
                client=new Socket(ip_add,port_add);
                ObjectOutputStream oos=new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
                Log.i("JSON",""+json);
                oos.writeObject(json);
                ObjectInputStream ois=new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());
                Log.i("OIS","Inside MyTask "+ois);
                byte[] buffer=(byte[]) ois.readObject();
                BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inMutable=true;
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(buffer, 0, buffer.length,options);
                oos.flush();
                ois.close();
                client.close();
                return bitmap;
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        if(result!=null){
            iv=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.screenView);
            ob=new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),result);
            iv.setBackgroundDrawable(ob);
            if(!new SendEvent(null).isCancelled()){
                Serializer ma=new Serializer(4,"ScreenShot");
                String json=ObjectSerializer(ma);
                task=new SendEvent(json);
                task.execute();
            }
        }else{
            Log.d("Bitmap null","Empty");
        }
    }
}


public String ObjectSerializer(Serializer serialize){
    Gson gs=new Gson();
    String gs_serial=gs.toJson(serialize);
    return gs_serial;
}


@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    task.cancel(true);
    task.isCancelled();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

}

LogCat

```
03-09 17:51:19.600: D/dalvikvm(31906): GC_CONCURRENT freed 86K, 9% free 12462K/13575K, paused 40ms+32ms, total 94ms
03-09 17:51:19.775: D/dalvikvm(31906): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 9% free 12459K/13575K, paused 13ms, total 13ms
03-09 17:51:19.785: I/dalvikvm-heap(31906): Grow heap (frag case) to 17.113MB for 4196368-byte allocation
03-09 17:51:19.805: D/dalvikvm(31906): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 7% free 16557K/17735K, paused 11ms+2ms, total 23ms
03-09 17:51:20.585: D/dalvikvm(31906): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 181K, 8% free 16560K/17927K, paused 21ms, total 21ms
03-09 17:51:20.600: I/dalvikvm-heap(31906): Grow heap (frag case) to 21.118MB for 4196368-byte allocation
03-09 17:51:20.630: D/dalvikvm(31906): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 7% free 20657K/22087K, paused 12ms+2ms, total 27ms
03-09 17:51:21.555: D/dalvikvm(31906): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4279K, 26% free 16561K/22087K, paused 29ms, total 29ms
03-09 17:51:21.555: I/dalvikvm-heap(31906): Grow heap (frag case) to 21.119MB for 4196368-byte allocation
03-09 17:51:21.595: D/dalvikvm(31906): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 7% free 20659K/22087K, paused 13ms+4ms, total 41ms
03-09 17:51:22.150: D/dalvikvm(31906): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4279K, 26% free 16562K/22087K, paused 21ms, total 21ms
03-09 17:51:22.155: I/dalvikvm-heap(31906): Grow heap (frag case) to 21.120MB for 4196368-byte allocation
03-09 17:51:22.180: D/dalvikvm(31906): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 7% free 20660K/22087K, paused 12ms+1ms, total 25ms
03-09 17:51:22.515: D/dalvikvm(31906): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4279K, 26% free 16559K/22087K, paused 12ms, total 12ms
```

Comment: `When the processing of Gargabe cleaner cause skip more than 10 frames.` ????

Comment: `oos.flush();` You could do that directly after writeObject. Before the read. It does not make sense there having received the answer.

Comment: Try to understand my code. `ObjectOutputStream ()` is not the cause for the lag. I am purely talking about the image receiving part.

Comment: @greenapps pls dont give useless answers.